# What happens if a person tries to log in with the same user account as someone who has already logged in?

Tags: ubuntu

I am currently logged into a remote server using a particular user account.
I kicked off a really long-running script, and have no idea when it will finish. It is blocking me from using the terminal that I connected to the server with.

What will happen if I open a second terminal and connect with the same user account to the same server? Will it log off my connection from the other terminal, and interrupt / kill the other running script?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have multiple connections without a problem. Each connection will have its own shell.

In the future you may want to start the script with nohup and background the script. This will allow the script to continue to run, even if you loose your shell. Also you can continue to use your existing shell without needing to open a new connection

```
nohup ./foo.sh &
```

Answer (score 6):

No, it won't log you off.
Linux (and pretty much any UNIX-like OS) is a multi-user, multi-session environment, so in your example, you'll have two independent user sessions.